# Who is successfully using git-flow?

Tags: git, workflow, git-flow

Are any large software projects using [git-flow](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow) and, if so, how is it going?

(See http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/ and http://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2010/why-arent-you-using-git-flow/)

Comment: The thing about git-flow is that it's pretty much just the way you'll end up using git if you really understand branching and merging. It's not really very far from the workflow for Git itself - change "develop" to "next", "release branches" to "maint", add on a "pu" branch for unstable testing (before merging to next), send everything through Junio Hamano instead of letting everyone push to the central repo, and you're pretty much there. If anyone's using it (well, understanding it and using it right), it's going well for them.

Comment: I am specifically referring to the git-flow command line tool, not to the branching model.

Comment: That wasn't particularly clear from your question (which you're welcome to edit) but given that the command-line tool is fairly trivial, and just helps you enforce the branch naming and remember to merge the right way, I think what I said still holds: if you're using it (right), it's going well.

Comment: what about windows support and any docs?

Comment: Discussion on Quora: http://www.quora.com/Git-revision-control/Who-is-using-git-flow

Answer (score 15):

I've introduced git flow in our team this week and am using it myself for a few weeks now and I absolutely love it. It makes branching and merging back so much easier. It can all be done with default git but git flow makes it so much easier and the branching model is fairly easy to understand and explain to new team members.

I'm all pro

Answer (score 4):

Introduced to a 4 developers team last week.
Seems to be going really well, we just had positive feedback so far.

I've been using it for my personal work for about 2,5 weeks and I am **very** happy with it.
Besides the time optimization, the ease to keep things tidy is evident.

Answer (score 4):

I introduced it to my company iSeatz, who has 15 to 20 programmers and 20 or so foreign contract UI guys. It was bumpy at first, but I managed to shape it into a well oiled machine with the help of my co-workers.

Answer (score 3):

[Yipit](http://yipit.com) uses it and it works well for a 6 person development team.